# Super + key above tab to switch between different instances of same app doesn't work

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, application-switcher

I only recently stumbled upon this problem in Ubuntu 23.10.

I use Super + the key above tab (tilde on Qwerty keyboards) to switch between different instances of the same app (Chrome, for instance). In vanilla GNOME, this is the default behaviour, but then with the ALT key instead of the Super key.

Scrolling between apps using Super + TAB does work. When there are multiple instances, however, it does reveal these, but I can't switch between them using the Tilde key. The instances are just being shown, without any instance hightligthed.

Using the arrow keys to switch between the instances does work.

Is this a bug? Is there a way to bring back this functionality?